# Get the content of a page's child in TYPO3

Tags: html, macos, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using Typo3.6.4 on Mac OS.

I want to get the content from a sub page.
The content is in the 3 sub page and it needs to display in the "Page" with TypoScript:

Page

-SubPage 1

-SubPage 2

-SubPage 3

I had try this code on Typo3.6.0 with Windows and it's working. But not with Typo3.6.4 on Mac OS.

```
  MIDBLOCK = CONTENT
  MIDBLOCK {
  stdWrap.wrap = |
    table = pages
    select.orderBy = sorting
    # If this element is inserted as sitemap, consider the startingpoint
    select.pidInList.if.isTrue.field = pages
    select.pidInList.field = pages
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
      stdWrap.wrap = |

      10 = CONTENT
      10.wrap = <div><h1>|</h1>
      10 {
        table = tt_content
        select.pidInList.field = uid
        select.where = colPos = 1
        select.orderBy = sorting
        renderObj = COA


        #read the bodytext
        renderObj.10 = TEXT
        renderObj.10.field = header
      }

      20 = TEXT
      20.value = Event
      20.typolink.parameter.field = uid


      # Title and link to the page
      30 = TEXT
      30.wrap = </div><div><h2>|</h2>
      30.field = title
      # 2. CONTENT object for reading the first content element
      40 = CONTENT
      40 {
        table = tt_content
        select.pidInList.field = uid
        select.where = colPos = 0
        select.orderBy = sorting
        renderObj = COA


        #read the bodytext
        renderObj.10 = TEXT
        renderObj.10 {
          field = bodytext
          #cut after 20 chars, keep whole words if possible
          crop = 20| ... |1
        }
      }
      # more link
      50 = TEXT
      50.wrap = <br /><br />|</div>
      50.value = > [More]
      50.typolink.parameter.field = uid
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love to answer myself to my question <3

So, the problem come to the Item "css_styled_content", on the first one, I didn't use that but on the the second one, I used this Item and it's doesn't work.

So if you want to write like me, you need to desactivate the Item or search again and again :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have included your TypoScript via

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source=FILE:EXT:my_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt>
```

This will no longer work in TYPO3 6.2. You have to add quotes like this:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:my_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt">
```

Comment: It's not that, because the rest of my typoscript works. I'ts just to get the content of subpage that I can't.